# 400. That’s an error. Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: redirect

google sign in authentication is working in my default page, but not in others which has a master page. It is hitting the error, tried to fix the issue in Google API Access, but is having the previous developer login details. So,please help me in what way can I resolve this issue. thanx in advance.

Comment: I don't know whether is it possible to create a new project for the same website. Will it reflect anywhere or anything goes wrong?

Comment: If we don't delete the previous one, can we create the new one and use it?

Comment: Changes means i cannot change the domain name right, there's no possibility. If any chances, please let me know clearly ma'am. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the console for your project and look under API Access. You should see your client ID & secret there, along with a list of redirect URIs. If the URI you want isn't listed, click edit settings and add the URI to the list.

Comment: Project console is not available, it is developed by ex-developer. He is not available, so we don't have the login details. Is there any other way solve this issue?

Comment: Then create new project in google so that you can solve the problem.

Comment: No problem you can create . If you know the Ex-Developer means tell him to delete the project in his google console so that you can create new project.